# SwiftUI use TabView with Picker

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to use a `Picker` to change the selected tab.

The issue is that when I tap on the picker, the content changes without animation.

Scrolling between tabs works correctly (the picker animates accordingly).

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var tabSelectedValue = 0

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        
        Picker("", selection: $tabSelectedValue) {
            Text("First").tag(0)
            Text("Second").tag(1)
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        .padding()
         
        TabView(selection: $tabSelectedValue) {
         
            Text("Content for first tab")
                .tag(0)
        
            Text("Content for second tab")
                .tag(1)
            
            
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
    .padding()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Picker` with `SegmentedPickerStyle` have default animation. So when you change the tab it's animating `Picker`. To animate `TabView` when you change `tabSelectedValue` you need to add the animation `ViewModier` to your `TabView`. Add `animation(_:value:)` modifier to your `TabView`.

```
.animation(.easeIn, value: tabSelectedValue)
```